# Jquery data-live-search is not working when populating select box through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get `data-live-search` option when the select box is populated through JQUERY my code is as follow

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $('#add').on('click', function () {

            var inp = $('#box');
            var i = $('input').length + 1;
            $('<div id="box' + i + '" class="col-lg-12"><table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-responsive">\n\
                    <tbody>\n\
                        <tr>\n\
                            <td  style="width: 39%;"><select id="item" class="form-control selectpicker" name="item[]" data-live-search="true">\n\
                            </select></td>\n\
                            <td><input type="text" id="qty" class="form-control" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" required/></td>\n\
                            <td><input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control" name="amount[]" placeholder="Amount" required/></td>\n\
                        </tr>\n\
                    </tbody>\n\
                </table></div>').appendTo(inp);
            i++;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now, this code is working fine but when I add `class="selectpicker"` the select box disappear.
Can someone please help me how to achieve that.

And here is my html code of including these scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use like this

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

**OR**

```
$('#selectID').selectpicker();
```

**OR**

```
$('select').selectpicker('refresh');
```

after append method.

Comment: I have tried this right now but this gives me error in the console that says

create:500 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function
    at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous> (create:500)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.dispatch (app.js:29)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.g.handle (app.js:29)

Comment: add bootstrap-select script reference end of the page

Comment: Added those below as well but still same issue